# Use of If statement with multiple conditions

Tags: vba, if-statement

I have written the following code which is basically supposed colour some boxes accordingly. Whenever i run this code, it runs the first case i.e. even when some other case is required to be selected. here is the code.

```
Sub Macro_quaterly()
If Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 1 Or 2 Or 3 Then
    Range("D7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        '.Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Sheet2.Cells(6, 11) = "rrrrrrr"
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 4 Or 5 Or 6 Or 7 Then
    Range("D7:E7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        '.Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Sheet2.Cells(6, 12) = "rddddddr"
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 8 Or 9 Or 10 Or 11 Then
 Range("D7:F7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 12 Or 13 Or 14 Or 15 Then
 Range("D7:G7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 16 Or 17 Or 18 Or 19 Then
 Range("D7:H7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 20 Or 21 Or 22 Or 23 Then
 Range("D7:I7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 24 Or 25 Or 26 Or 27 Then
 Range("D7:J7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 28 Or 29 Or 30 Or 31 Then
 Range("D7:K7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 32 Or 33 Or 34 Or 35 Then
 Range("D7:L7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 36 Or 37 Or 38 Or 39 Then
 Range("D7:M7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 40 Or 41 Or 42 Or 43 Then
 Range("D7:N7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 44 Or 45 Or 46 Or 47 Then
 Range("D7:O7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 48 Or 49 Or 50 Or 51 Then
 Range("D7:P7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 52 Or 53 Or 54 Or 55 Then
 Range("D7:Q7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 56 Or 57 Or 58 Or 59 Then
 Range("D7:R7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) = 60 Then
 Range("D7:S7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dude. Could you post that in [code] tags and with, like, a line-break or two?

Comment: Wow! I wish could read that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 If Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 1 Or 2 Or 3 Then
```

This line is not doing what you think it is doing.  You need to put `If Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 1 Or Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 2 Or Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 3 Or Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 4 Then` (or substitute an intermediate variable in for `Sheet2.Range("B6").Value`)

Comment: I've always wanted to see support for if `(foo == (bar OR baz OR biz))`... since it seems I keep typing things that way, initially....

Answer (score 10):

An alternative is to use `Select..Case` statements.  I think it is a lot more readable for this kind of thing:

```
Select Case Sheet2.Range("B6").Value 
Case 1, 2, 3
    Range("D7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        '.Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Sheet2.Cells(6, 11) = "rrrrrrr"
    End With
Case 4, 5, 6, 7
    Range("D7:E7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        '.Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Sheet2.Cells(6, 12) = "rddddddr"
    End With
Case .... 
    ....   
Case Else
    ....
End Select
```

Comment: I would probably argue that this is the best way of doing it - and reading the OP's question he used the "Case" phrase - so maybe this was the initial intent?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your problem lies in the fact that the numbers in your `Or` conditions are implicitly coerced to Boolean values, and that when this happens, everything except 0 is coerced to `True`. To convince yourself of this, try `Debug.Print CBool(13)` and `Debug.Print CBool(0)`.

I am a bit peeved that none of the people who have posted previous answers have explained this, hence this post which might otherwise have been considered repetitive!

Instead of

```
If Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 1 Or 2 Or 3 Then
```

use

```
If Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 1 Or _
    Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 2 Or _
    Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 3 Then
```

etc.  Or, even better, a `Select Case` construct as suggested by @mwolfe02.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
So the problem here is the "If statement".

The correct way of defining the 'OR' is as so

```
If Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 1 Or Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 2 Or Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = 3 Then
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the errors noted by the other answers posted here, it is important to note the construct used for testing your condition is `If` with `ElseIf`. By using this to test your condition, you will always execute the first `ElseIf` condition resolving to `True` and skip any later conditions which may be defined.

This means you may end up with logical issues in formatting according to the appropriate conditions you intended to format.

For this reason, I would recommend using the `Case` statement construct as provided by @mwolfe02 in the response above along with all similar formatting conditions within the same `Case` statement. This would prevent various formatting situations from occurring based on what conditions had been met in a particular ordering of data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey..theres another problem am facing in the same code..i guess it should be simple but am really new to vba..could anybody help me pls..I am using the following vba code to simply assign the value of an existing cell to another cell in another sheet..but it gives a runtime error 424..Kindly help..the code reads as follows

Sub Selection_cell_for_payoff_quaterly()

If Sheet2.Cells(6, 2).Value = 1 Then

Sheet2.Cells(7, 2).Value = Sheet6.Range("D7").Value

End If

End Sub

Comment: @mehak: Please don't ask new questions in comments. Just post a new question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "logical issues in formatting according to the appropriate conditions". `If` constructs and `Select Case` constructs are, in principle, [completely interchangeable](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvbnet/a/blecvbsbs0704.htm). The difference between the two is mainly cosmetic. Don't get me wrong, cosmetics are important when they affect readability. But I don't know of any "logical issues in formatting". Note that in VBA's `Select Case`, the first `Case` that resolves to true is executed, and all others are skipped --just like `If-ElseIf`.

Comment: What I mean by logical issues is when the specific condition is met what formatting should be applied, in so much as formatting done on a cell which was not intended to be formatted a specific way. You are correct of the logical equivalence in "If" and "Case" constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of redundant code you can get rid of and as mentioned a couple of times go with select case.

Try:

```
Sub Macro_quaterly()
    Dim rCell As Range

    Select Case Sheet2.Range("B6").Value
    Case 1, 2, 3
        Set rCell = Range("D7")
        Sheet2.Cells(6, 11) = "rrrrrrr"
    Case 4, 5, 6, 7
        Set rCell = Range("D7:E7")
        Sheet2.Cells(6, 12) = "rddddddr"
    Case 8, 9, 10, 11
        Set rCell = Range("D7:F7")

    Case Else

    End Select

    With rCell.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Set rCell = Nothing

End Sub
```