# Type Mismatch Error IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I am trying to make a 'Sales Page' where the user can enter in details of a sale for each day. I am using a user form for it and i am trying to make it that when you enter the day, if it is incorrect then display a message box and don't run the rest of the function. Anyway, i keep getting the type mismatch error on this part of the code and i don't know why

`If salday <> "Monday" _
Or "Tuesday" _
Or "Wednesday" _
Or "Thursday" _
Or "Friday" _
Or "Saturday" _
Or "Sunday" Then
MsgBox "Incorrect Day. Please make sure you are using capitals!"
Else`

If anyone could help that would be great :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of If statement in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306159/use-of-if-statement-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dim salday  as string
If salday <> "Monday" _
and salday <> "Tuesday" _
and salday <> "Wednesday" _
and salday <> "Thursday" _
and salday <> "Friday" _
and salday <> "Saturday" _
and salday <> "Sunday" Then
MsgBox "Incorrect Day. Please make sure you are using capitals!"
Else
```