# Excel VBA - How do I refer to a cell's visible content rather than its formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop through a particular range in my Excel spreadsheet(("B13:B65"), to be specific)  and hide all rows that have an "X" in them. Something like this:

```
For i = 13 to 65
If Cells(i, 2) = "x" Or "X" Then Rows(i).RowHeight = 0
Next i
```

The problem is that I'm getting a type mismatch error.

I assume this is happening because all the cells in this range are formulas rather than text strings. For example, the contents of cell B13 are:

```
='Monthly'!$C$13
```

I want my code to evaluate the visible output of the cell, not the actual content.

I get the feeling there's a very easy solution here, but I've been searching for a while with no success. I'm a rookie, obviously...

Comment: Here's the explanation for and answer to your actual problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6308366/119775

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of If statement with multiple conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306159/use-of-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 5):

Based on this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx

```
Sub Main()

For Each c in Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10")    'Change for your range
 If Lcase(c.Value) = "x" Then 
 '''Rest of your code
 End If 
Next c

end sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because of the OR.  There has to be something that can be evaluated to true or false after the Or.  Or "X" won't ever be true or false.  You need...

`If Cells(i, 2) = "x" Or Cells(i, 2) = "X" Then Rows(i).RowHeight = 0`

As long as you wanted to use the same code everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Use Value property:

```
If Cells(i, 2).Value = "x"
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through static range

```
Dim rng As Range, c As Range
Set rng = Range("B13:B65")

For Each c In rng.Cells
    If UCase(c) = "X" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AutoFilter

```
Sub HideEm()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$65")
rng1.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>x", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>X"
End Sub
```